# Listview in detail pane of Android

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

1. I am new to android, so I'm trying various examples. In one specific
   example using fragment, I made list view and made it two view on
   both phone and tablet screen[master/detail fragment].
2. I tried with example of viewing text and image in detail pane. But I am unable to make a list in the detailed view.
3. When I **click Item1 in master** , it must **show a textview in detail fragment** and when I **click on Item2 in master**, It must **show me a Listview in detail fragment.**
4. If possible can you provide me a general code format.

Comment: Share some code what you ever tried ?

Answer (score 0):

You should first get reference to both items you want to show ie TextView and ListView. I think you should know how to do that having reached here :)

Now, in master, in its OnItemClickListener, check if its item1 or item2,
then modify the visibility of your views using :

```
TextView.setVisibility(VISIBLE); //Visible is an android constant = 0;
ListView.setVisibility(INVISIBLE); // INVISIBLE = 4;
```

.. and vice versa.

Hope this helps :)